# How can I pass an object or variable along with Promise.all?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am having an issue where I want to send some requests to Plaid asking for account information, but when it's returned, I don't know where to associate the account information so I need to pass along an ID like `source.id`. Problem is `Promise.all` does not work with the way I've written things below. Is there another way to accomplish this so I can get back the ID I need?

````
var userSources = firestore.collection('sources');
    userSources.get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var source = doc.data();
            sources.push(source);
        });
    return sources;

    }).then((sources) => {
        // 2: Connect to Plaid and query accounts
        var promises = [];
        sources.forEach(function(source) {
            promises.push({
                id: source.id,
                p: client.getBalance(source.access_token)
            });
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);

    }).then...
    ```
````

Comment: I'm assuming `getBalance` returns the Promise you want to consume, right?

Comment: Yes! `client.getBalance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to end up with an array if objects that have `id` and `balance` in them, you can do something like this.  You call `client.getBalance()` and in the `.then()` handler you create the object you want in the result that combines `source.id` with the `balance` and you return that as the resolved value from the promise.  You can then run `Promise.all()` on that array of promises and get the appropriate array of objects as the result.

```
let userSources = firestore.collection('sources');
userSources.get().then(snapshot => {
    return Promise.all(snapshot.map(doc => {
        let source = doc.data();
        return client.getBalance(source.access_token).then(balance => {
            return {id: source.id, balance: balance};
        });
    }));
}).then(results => {
    // array of {id, balance} objects
    console.log(results);
});
```

This has an advantage that it puts the balance and corresponding id in the same array of objects rather than in separate arrays.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using `await` instead, so the `sources` array in created in the upper part of the code, but is still visible to everything below it. Make sure the containing function is async, then:

```
const snapshot = await firestore.collection('sources').get();
const sources = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
const promises = sources.map(source => client.getBalance(source.access_token));
const results = await Promise.all(promises);
// now, results[i] will correspond to sources[i].id
```

Note that you can use `.map` to transform one array into another, which is a bit more appropriate than `forEach`.

Comment: What you're sending to `Promise.all()` is not an array of promises so `Promise.all()` doesn't do anything useful with it.

Comment: Oops, yeah, that was definitely a plain object, not a Promise...

Comment: When I try this code I get `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` inside of Node on Firebase.

Comment: @boxmatic Like I said in the answer, *Make sure the containing function is async* - that allows you to use `await` inside it, which makes the code a lot flatter, allowing you to define the `sources` array above and use it after asynchronous actions below without troubles. It'a also a lot more readable. There are workarounds without `await`, but they're a whole lot uglier IMO

Comment: If you get `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` then you didn't make the containing function async.

Comment: Did you try making the containing function `async`?